# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (156x551 and 512x128)

Tags: artificial-intelligence

When attempting to incorporate information about surface_emotion alongside text embeddings into the recurrent neural network (RNN) for sequence modeling, an error occurred. Specifically, the issue arose when concatenating the output of the LSTM layer with the surface emotions and passing it through the first fully connected layer (fc1). This problem occurred despite the successful operation when excluding surface_emotion, indicating that the addition of this information disrupted the expected tensor dimensions.

The error message highlights a mismatch in tensor shapes during the matrix multiplication operation performed by the fc1 layer. It indicates that the shapes of matrices mat1 and mat2 are incompatible for multiplication. mat1 has a shape of (156x551), while mat2 has a shape of (512x128), indicating that the number of columns in mat1 does not match the number of rows in mat2, hence the multiplication operation cannot be performed.

This issue suggests that the concatenation operation introduced an unexpected change in the dimensions of the input tensor, leading to a mismatch when passing it through the fully connected layer. To resolve this problem, it's crucial to ensure that the dimensions of the tensors being concatenated and subsequently passed through the fully connected layer are compatible with the expected input dimensions of the layer. This may involve reshaping or adjusting the dimensions of the tensors to ensure compatibility.

my code:

```
# Define the sentiment analysis model class
class SentimentAnalysisModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, pretrained_embedding=None,
                 num_layers=1, bidirectional=False, dropout=0.5):  
        super(SentimentAnalysisModel, self).__init__()
        
        # Initialize the embedding layer
        if pretrained_embedding is not None:
            self.embedding = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(pretrained_embedding, freeze=True)
        else:
            self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        
        # Initialize the LSTM layer
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers=num_layers, bidirectional=bidirectional,
                           batch_first=True)
        
        # Initialize the dropout layer
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

        # Initialize the first fully connected layer
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim * 2 if bidirectional else hidden_dim, 128)
        # Initialize the second fully connected layer
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, output_dim)

    # Define the forward pass of the model
    def forward(self, text, surface_emotion):
        # Embed the text
        embedded = self.embedding(text)
        # Pass the embedded text through the LSTM layer
        output, _ = self.rnn(embedded)
        
        # Apply dropout to the output
        output = self.dropout(output)

        # Process surface emotions
        surface_emotion = surface_emotion.transpose(0, 1).unsqueeze(1)
        surface_emotion = surface_emotion.repeat(1, output.size(1), 1)

        # Concatenate the output of the LSTM with surface emotions
        combined_output = torch.cat((output, surface_emotion), dim=-1)
        
        # Flatten the combined output
        combined_output = combined_output.view(-1, combined_output.size(2)) 
        
        # Pass the combined output through the first fully connected layer
        output = self.fc1(combined_output)
        output = F.relu(output)
        # Pass the output through the second fully connected layer
        output = self.fc2(output)
        
        return output

# Define the number of output dimensions
output_dim = len(HIDE_EMOTION_LABELS)  #
models = []

# Create multiple models based on the specified number
for _ in range(config["num_models"]):
    model = SentimentAnalysisModel(vocab_size=len(TEXT.vocab),
                                   embedding_dim=100,
                                   hidden_dim=256,
                                   output_dim=output_dim,
                                   bidirectional=True)
    models.append(model)

# Define the loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
# Initialize optimizers for each model
optimizers = [optim.Adam(model.parameters()) for model in models]

# Define the training function
def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0
    for batch in iterator:
        text = batch.text
        surface_emotion = batch.hide_emotion.long()

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        output = model(text, surface_emotion)
        loss = criterion(output.view(-1, output.shape[-1]), batch.hide_emotion.view(-1)) 

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        epoch_loss += loss.item()

    return epoch_loss / len(iterator)

# Define the evaluation function
def evaluate(model, iterator, criterion):
    model.eval()
    epoch_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in iterator:
            text = batch.text
            surface_emotion = batch.hide_emotion.long()

            output = model(text, surface_emotion)

            loss = criterion(output.view(-1, output.shape[-1]), batch.hide_emotion.view(-1))

            epoch_loss += loss.item()

    return epoch_loss / len(iterator)

# Iterate over epochs and models for training
for epoch in range(config["num_epochs"]):
    
    for i, model in enumerate(models):
        train_loss = train(model, train_iterator, optimizers[i], criterion)
        val_loss = evaluate(model, val_iterator, criterion)

        print(f'Epoch: {epoch + 1:02} | Model: {i + 1:02}')
        print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train PPL: {math.exp(train_loss):7.3f}')
        print(f'\t Val. Loss: {val_loss:.3f} |  Val. PPL: {math.exp(val_loss):7.3f}')
```

```
Combined output shape before linear layer: torch.Size([4, 39, 551])
Linear layer weight shape: torch.Size([128, 512])
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\桌面\Zu_bot\AI\Zu_AI(en2).py", line 293, in <module>
    train_loss = train(model, train_iterator, optimizers[i], criterion)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\桌面\Zu_bot\AI\Zu_AI(en2).py", line 262, in train
    output = model(text, surface_emotion)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\桌面\Zu_bot\AI\Zu_AI(en2).py", line 205, in forward
    output = self.fc1(combined_output)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 114, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (156x551 and 512x128)
```

Comment: Did you just paste the output of some LLM into the question field? Because it sure looks like it ...